# How to delete Docker Image on Azure Container Registry in Java?

Tags: java, docker

I'm looking for a way to delete Docker Image on Azure Container Registry in Java.
I want to delete only the Docker Image.
I don't want to delete the container registry.

I'm checking the operation according to this Azure sample project, but I don't know how to do it.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/acr-java-manage-azure-container-registry

I read the official document and googled it, but I couldn't find a way to do it, so I asked a question.
If you know how to do it, please let me know.

Comment: Do you want to delete just once manually or in an automated way from code?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the documentation which guides you how to delete images in a repository

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-delete#delete-by-tag

To delete an image from java, try the below command

```
dockerClient.removeImageCmd("beaccc8687ae").exec();
```

Reference - https://www.baeldung.com/docker-java-api#7-remove-an-image

Comment: thank you for your answer.  
I want to manually delete it from Java code only once.  
I don't want to operate with az cli.  
  
The image is as follows.（Case to push）  
  
// Push the new Docker image to the Azure Container Registry//                                                                                               
dockerClient.pushImageCmd(privateRepoUrl).withAuthConfig(dockerClient.authConfig()).exec(new PushImageResultCallback()).awaitSuccess();

Comment: Updated the answer, Let me know if it helps.

Comment: If the answer works, it would help if you could mark the answer as accepted/correct as it will help others too.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in contacting you.
I've tried that method, but I was only able to delete the local Docker Image. If you know how to delete a Docker Image on Azure Container Registry that way, please let me know.